# Export one SAS table into multiple Excel worksheets based on field value

Tags: excel, sas

I'm trying to export one SAS table into multiple Excel worksheets based on the value of a field (parent_account). I want each worksheet to be named the same as the parent_account. I'm using the following code that I found at http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1335588, but I'm getting these error messages:

A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required.
Argument 2 to macro function %SCAN is not a number.

```
%macro export_to_excel();
%local varlist idx var;

proc sql noprint;
  select distinct parent_account into: varlist separated by '||'
  from todays_activity;
quit;

%let idx = 1;
%do %while ( %scan(&varlist, &idx, %str(||)) ne %str() ); 
    %let var=%scan(&varlist, &idx, %str(||));
    proc export data=sashelp.class (where=(parent_account="&var"))
       outfile='My file location\Report.xls'
   dbms=excel; 
   sheet="&var";
quit;
%let idx = %eval(&idx + 1);
%end;
%mend export_to_excel;

%export_to_excel;
```

Comment: What version of SAS are you using.  If you are using current version you could try using ODS EXCEL and adjust when it makes a new sheet to be for each BY group. Then just use PROC PRINT with a BY statement.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that. I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 7.11.

Comment: What version of SAS your EG session is connecting to is more important for the EG version.

Comment: That I'm not sure of. Is there a simple way to verify?

Comment: `%put &sysvlong;`  Mine says 9.04.01M3P062415

Comment: Same: 9.04.01M3P062415

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `ODS EXCEL`.  Here is an example use SASHELP.CLASS dataset.
First make sure the data is sorted by your grouping variables.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class ;
  by sex ;
run;
```

Set up ODS to point to your target file. Tell it to make a new sheet for each BY group.

```
ods excel file="&path/class.xlsx"  ;
ods excel options
(sheet_interval="bygroup"
 suppress_bylines="yes"
 sheet_name='GENDER'
);
```

You also might want to turn off other output destinations.
Then print the file using PAGEBY option. And close the ODS EXCEL destination

```
proc print data=class noobs;
  by sex ;
  pageby sex ;
  var _all_;
run;
ods excel close;
```

To test it you could try reading it back in as data.  But watch out that it will create member names with embedded spaces.

```
options validmemname=extend;
libname xx xlsx "&path/class.xlsx";
proc copy inlib=xx outlib=work; run;
libname xx clear ;
```

From SAS log

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.GENDER has 9 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: The data set WORK.'GENDER 2'n has 10 observations and 5 variables.
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. After running the second part of this code, I'm getting a warning: Unsupported device 'ACTIVEX' for EXCEL destination. Using device 'ACTXIMG'.

Comment: Did if still make the XLSX file? I would think that would only apply if you were trying to make a graph. Perhaps your TITLE or FOOTNOTE statements triggered that message?

Comment: It did make an XLSX file, but it was corrupt and failed to open.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
%macro export_to_excel;
    proc sql noprint;
    select distinct parent_account into: varlist separated by '@' from todays_activity;
    select count(distinct parent_account) into:n from todays_activity;
    quit;
    %do i=1 %to &n;
    %let var= %scan(&varlist,&i,"@");
    proc export data=sashelp.class (where=(parent_account="&var"))
           outfile='Your file location\Report.xls'
       dbms=excel; 
       sheet="&var";
    run;
    %end;
    %mend export_to_excel;
```

Comment: Oddly, it runs quickly, with one note and no warnings or errors: NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR. No file is created. Am I missing a line of code?